# Get List values To 2D array and Retrive

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, foreach, jstl

I tried to put java list into a 2D array and Retrieve it from the JSP. But It wasn't success.I really need this done.. Support me if you can..I have put my codes below if you able to solve this I'm really appreciate that.

**Update:**
   1st List is getting inserted to first row(I want it insert to first column). likewise other three lists inserted to other 3 rows instead of three columns.
**Screenshot**
[image]

**Requirement :**
Ex:-

[image]

**Servlet Code.**

```
Scanner scanner  = new Scanner(Result);
        List<String> cdLine = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Integer> wtc = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> ncc = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> ccpps = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ControlData controlData = new ControlData();
        while(scanner.hasNextLine())  
        {  
            token1 = scanner.nextLine();
            Wtcs = controlData.CtrlWeight(token1);
            NC = controlData.NofConditions(token1);
            Ccspps = controlData.previousComplex(token1);
            cdLine.add(token1);
            wtc.add(Ccspps);
            ncc.add(NC);
            ccpps.add(Wtcs);

            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            List arr[][]={{cdLine},{wtc},{ncc},{ccpps}};  
        }  

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        List arr[][]={{cdLine},{wtc},{ncc},{ccpps}};  
        scanner.close();     //close the scanner  
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/views/Control_structures.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("Code_string", arr);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

**JSP code(using JSTL)**

```
<c:forEach items="${Code_string}" var="post" varStatus="theCount">
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${post}" var="value" varStatus="cell">
            <tr>
                <td scope="row">${theCount.count}</td>
                <td>${value[0]}</td>
                <td>${value[1]}</td>
                <td>${value[2]}</td>
                <td>${value[3]}</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</c:forEach>
```

**Update 2:**
The 2D array that parsing to the JSP is like this. Hope this also need to be changed.

> [[[public class Prime {, if,     public static void main(String[]
>   args) {, ,         int low = 20, high = 50;, ,         while (low <
>   high) {,             if(checkPrimeNumber(low)),
>   System.out.print(low + " ");, ,             ++low;,         },     },
>   ,     public static boolean checkPrimeNumber(int num) {,
>   boolean flag = true;, ,         for(int i = 2; i <= num/2; ++i) {, ,
>   if(num % i == 0) {,                 flag = false;,
>   break;,             },         }, ,         return flag;,     }, }]],
>   [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]

**Output that I'm getting:**
[image]
Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: What are the errors that you are getting? Did you try debugging?

Comment: @Yserbius it's getting all 4 lists into four rows. Let me update the question with an screen shot

Comment: @Yserbius can you  have a look now?

Comment: What's it supposed to show?

Comment: @Yserbius I have added 4 lists into a 2D array. So What I want is I want to show those 4 lists into 4 columns but here it's showing in 4 columns.

Comment: @Yserbius I have added a example of my requirement

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I'm creating a code complexity measuring tool.. public static void main is just a string . here I'm measuring complexity of java code.. Hope you got it. have a look of Requirement part.. Thank you.. Give me your support to get this done

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code:

**A.** With the following statement, you have created a 3-D structure which is an array **of** arrays **of** lists (Note that the `List` is an implementation of a dynamic 1-D array).

```
List arr[][]={{cdLine},{wtc},{ncc},{ccpps}};
```

You need an array **of** lists as given below:

```
List arr[]={cdLine,wtc,ncc,ccpps};
```

**B.** Do not place the above line inside the `while` loop. Do it just once after the `while` loop.

Apart from the points mentioned above, I would recommend you create a custom type instead of using raw type for the `List` array. Your custom type should be something like:

```
class MyType {
    private List<String> cdLine = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<Integer> wtc = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private List<Integer> ncc = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private List<Integer> ccpps = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // ..constructors and getters and setters
}
```

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Now it's giving me an error in the JSP.. ${value[0]} is not working is there is anything to be fixed in the JSP aslo?

Comment: Use `${value.get(0)} ` as you are retrieving data from a `List` not an array. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: Still it's giving me the error.                                                                                                                Message :An exception occurred processing [/views/Control_structures.jsp] at line [57]

Description: The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. I think something wrong in those two foreachs. I'm new with JSTL could you please have a look that for each

Comment: Just use ${value} and run it. From the result, you will get to know what you need to do next. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: Still trying :(  Will see Avinash..